# How do i change My wishlist text to "Wishlist" in top links in magento 2

Tags: magento

I would like to change the the text My wishlist in the top links to just wish list in Magento 2? I've found where My account and create account are located but can't seem to find where My Wishlist is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title "My Wish List" is set from the below file :

```
vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Block/Link.php
```

in the function `getLabel()`

Override this block to change the label, according to your wish

Comment: How do I override block in my theme file structure?

Comment: follow this https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/Overriding-a-block-in-Magento-2/td-p/6831